# Video Output not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, media-player, ios6

I am making an app that can display a preloaded file on the ios simulator. Though the display screen shows on the simulator, I can't see the video nor hear the sound.

Here is my code.

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"

@implementation BIDViewController
@synthesize moviePlayer;


-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                pathForResource:@"SwimGood" ofType:@"m4v"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
//Play partial screen.

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(64, 100, 200, 150);

[self.view addSubview: player.view];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

[player play];
}
```

Comment: cheers! i've done that..thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Using like this

> NSString *videoFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
>   pathForResource:[tempDic objectForKey:@"VideoName"] ofType:@"mov"];
>
> ```
> NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilepath];
> ```
>
> MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
>       playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(6, 5, 308, 202);
>
> ```
> [playerViewController setContentURL:url];
> playerViewController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
> [playerViewController prepareToPlay];
>   [self.view addSubview:[playerViewController view]];
> ```

and It's working fine..so it might be a problem of file type. so try to use .mov

and Don't forgot to import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h
And Add MediaPlayer framework it not exists in your main bundle.

Best Luck...